# ASP DropDown Issue in chrome popup

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-chrome

I have developed asp.net application. In that application opening one page using `window.showModalDialog` using following script.

> var answer = window.showModalDialog(url, "Info", "dialogHeight:680px; dialogLeft:90px; dialogWidth:990px;center:yes;dialogTop:50px;status:no; scroll:yes;");

In popup page contains dropdown list and few text box controls. Once I click the dropdown list all text box will goes read-only also drop down list items not hiding (page was freeze).

when I right click that page (any place) text boxes readonly removed.

This exception was occur only in chrome browser, also I have changed chrome policy for working showmodeldialog.

Thanks

M. Prabhu

Comment: <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="KuttyProject._Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<div>
<fieldset>
<legend>Universe: </legend>
 <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlUnivers"  Width="150">
</asp:DropDownList>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<legend>Filter </legend>
<div style="width: 100%;">
<div style="float: left; width: 20%;">
<fieldset>

Comment: <legend>One</legend>
<asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="lb1" Width="150" Height="250"></asp:ListBox>
</fieldset>
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 20%;">
<fieldset>
<legend>Two</legend>
<asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="ListBox1" Width="150" Height="250"></asp:ListBox>
</fieldset>
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 10%; height:250">
<fieldset>
<legend>
Three
</legend>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text=">" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text=">>" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="<" />
</td>

Comment: </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="<<" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 20%;">
<fieldset>
<legend>
Four
</legend>
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox2" runat="server" Width="150" Height="250"></asp:ListBox>
</fieldset>
</div>
<div style="float: left;">
<fieldset>
<legend>
Five
</legend>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="150px" CellPadding="4" 
ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
<EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />

Comment: <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
<RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
<SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
<SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
<SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
<SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Add" />

Comment: <asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" Text="Edit" />
<asp:Button ID="Button6" runat="server" Text="Delete" />
</fieldset>
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
<center>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnGenerate" Text="Generate" />
</center>
</asp:Content>